# C++ static member initialization

Tags: c++, macros

I want to define class and register it with a macro. That is, run some runtime code to register type nodes so they could be traversed later.

```
#define DUMMY_REG(name,strname)  \
    struct name { template <class Any> name(Any&&,int i = \
        registerType()) {} name() {}    \
        static int registerType() {     \
            static int res = registerTypeInMap(strname,\
                makeTypeNodeFunction< name >(strname));\
            return res;\
        }\
        static int s_var = registerType();\
    };
```

So, basically I have static s_var and to initialize it I would want to run some function for it's side effects (which register a type). But, of course, I'm not allowed to initialize s_var inline. I have to do it out of bounds of a class. Which is a problem because I'd like to nest types like that:

```
struct ClassHolder {
    DUMMY_REG(TypeA,"Runtime_name_for_TypeA");
    DUMMY_REG(TypeB,"Runtime_name_for_TypeB");
};
```

I cannot write this in the end of the macro because it would still be in class scope. How do I make sure I run some static code before execution of main to define and register a certain type?

The main thing I want to avoid is redundant repetition, like one declaration for class and one macro for registering a type - that's redundant and stupid.

Comment: Why not providing another template like `template<typename Any, const char* Name> struct DummyReg {}` instead of the macro?

Comment: Ignoring the macro weirdness, all you have to do is define the statics as *something* and you can change them via a function if you choose to do so, at least as long as they are not `const static`. In any case, macros really shouldn't be used for this.

Comment: @WilliamKappler I want to only write once DUMMY_REG(mytime,"runtimename") and don't worry about it at all, the way you say it worked previously, I'd define structs and register them in another place, I want everything in one go. As soon as I enter main I want types to be ready.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to initialize `s_var` inline?

Comment: It's according to ISO rules, not sure about the technical reason behind this, but such initialization must appear outside class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it for now (maybe people hinted this way in comments, I'm not sure). Basically, I used helper type with a template which calls a function out of line to get int as a side effect, and then, you need to use that int so it would be instantiated (it can be ignored by the compiler) so I used that int as default parameter in constructor. Not sure how well this will scale, hopefully, this is cross platform.

```
#define DUMMY_REG(name,strname)  \
    struct name { template <class Any> name(Any&&,int reg = Regger::s_sideEffect) {} \
        TypeRegger<name> Regger; \
        name() {}    \
        static int registerType() {     \
            static int res = registerTypeInMap(strname,\
                makeTypeNodeFunction< name >(strname));\
            return res;\
        }\
    };


template <class T>
struct TypeRegger {
    static const int s_sideEffect;
};

template <class T>
const int TypeRegger<T>::s_sideEffect = T::registerType();
```